# GeoJSON API in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson

Can someone explain which kind of "arrangements" can be used to get data with QGIS API?

I am very new to QGIS API.

As I see it API's can be added by using Add Layers- Add WMS/WMTS Layer and by using  QGIS  Python console for GeoJSON.

In addition:

I have tried  to get data from meteorological URL holding GeoJSON, however when I selected connect in "Create a New WMS/WMTS Connection" I get error as on the snapshot.

Do I miss here some kind of authentication?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[WMS](https://www.ogc.org/standards/wms) is a protocol for image data (such as a PNG or JPEG). To directly access a [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) via a URL you can use the Add Vector Layer dialog (`Layer` -> `Add Layer` -> `Add Vector Layer...`). Set the `Source Type` to `Protocol HTTP(S), cloud, etc`, `Type` to `HTTP/HTTPS/FTP`, and enter your URL. Clicking  <kbd>Add</kbd> will give you a list of available layers.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the Python console / Script Editor

```py
url = 'https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?lat=60.10&lon=9.58'

gjson = QgsVectorLayer(url, 'geojson from url')

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(gjson)
```

*The following part is based on a discussion in the comments. Credit to @Marin Mirošević for finding [this blog post by Stephanie of open.gis.lab](https://opengislab.com/blog/2020/2/1/tip-on-adding-geojson-via-url-in-qgis)*

For some seemingly valid GeoJSON URLs, QGIS will display the following message. Clicking <kbd>Yes</kbd> will trigger a message referring to an invalid data source. Apparently it stems from an outdated `openssl` library.

[image]

[Stephanie's blog](https://opengislab.com/blog/2020/2/1/tip-on-adding-geojson-via-url-in-qgis) describes the issue in detail and offers a solution that involves adding a couple of environmental variables to QGIS. **I am no network specialist. This may have security implications, so use at your own risk**

> Change The Environmental Setting Variables In QGIS
>
> Go to Settings Menu >> Options
>
> In the Options window:
>
> Go System
>
> Expand Environment: check the box to Use custom variables
>
> Then add the following Variables
>
> Variable: GDAL_HTTP_USERAGENT
>
> Variable Value: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36
> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36
>
> Variable: GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL
>
> Variable Value: YES
>
> Restart QGIS and then try to add the GeoJSON file link again.

Comment: hi, i am trying to fetch this one  https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/documentation#!/data/get_compact

Comment: I have inputted  as per you snapshot but then i get  this warning. "Invalid Data Source: https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/documentation#!/data/get_compact is not a valid or recognized data source."

Comment: That is the URL for the API documentation. You must use a specific URL where you include a query for your desired location. Take a look at the [Sample URLs](https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/documentation#:~:text=for%20aviation%20purposes.-,Sample%20request%20URLs,complete%3Flat%3D%2D16.516667%26lon%3D%2D68.166667%26altitude%3D4150%20%20%20%23%20El%20Alto%2C%20Bolivia,-https%3A//api.met) section

Comment: tried as sample as you have suggested but got this error message. "    CRITICAL    Invalid Data Source : https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?lat=60.10&lon=9.58 is not a valid or recognized data source"

Comment: I experienced the same problem. See above for command to use in the Python console. If you are not comfortable with Python, you can also use the `Download File` tool in the processing toolbox and save the GeoJSON to disk before opening it QGIS.

Comment: Hi Matt  .  I got this info/help connected  to error message (connecting to Vector thatt you suggested).  "seems like QGIS is sending an empty User-Agent, which is not allowed. 
Outside of reporting this as a bug to the QGIS developers, the easiest way 
to remedy this is to run a local proxy (e.g. Nginx) which adds the necessary"
header to the outgoing request"

Comment: That is interesting. Good investigating :) Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with Nginx.

Comment: i also found this maybe interesting. https://opengislab.com/blog/2020/2/1/tip-on-adding-geojson-via-url-in-qgis

Comment: That is a great find. Did you try the solution? It worked for me, the URL that ws failing before now works `https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?lat=60.10&lon=9.58`

Comment: That is good. I tried to import sample  https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?lat=60.10&lon=9.58  but i dont think this is acually Geojson format. Although i  position imported but all oter fields come under one attribute "timestep" which i dont thik it should be hte case. Like for example given here https://www.nanaimo.ca/crimereporting/api/incidents.geojson

Comment: That is the way that particular GeoJSON is formatted. I have written a script to extract the data to a CSV. If you open a new question asking how to do so, I can post it there.

Comment: here it goes. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421023/geojson-format-to-csv