# GeoJSON format to CSV

Tags: qgis, geojson

How to extract the GeoJSON from the following URL to CSV ?

https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?lat=60.10&lon=9.58

Also what option to use to get/import  this data to layer?

Comment: Please ask only One question per Question.

Answer (score 8):

This particular GeoJSON has a list of nested dictionaries as one of its properties. The following script downloads the GeoJSON, creates a point layer which is added to the map canvas, and extracts the timestamp and associated data for each dictionary in the feature's property.

A Pandas DataFrame is made from the data and it is ultimately saved to a CSV and added to QGIS as a table.

Copy-paste the script into the Python Script editor and click <kbd>Run</kbd>.

```py
import ast
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?lat=60.10&lon=9.58'

## make a layer name with the data type and location in URL
name = url.split('/')[4] + ' | ' + url.split('?')[1].replace('&', ', ')

## make a vector layer from the url
gjson = QgsVectorLayer(url, name)

## add it to the map
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(gjson)

## get the only feature in the layer
f = list(gjson.getFeatures())[0]

## get the contents of the timeseries attribute field (a string of a list)
t = f['timeseries']

## safely evaluate the string as a list
t = ast.literal_eval(t)

## make an empty list to hold the data rows
data = []

## make the column headers from the nested dictionary keys
columns = ['time'] + list(t[0]['data']['instant']['details'].keys())

for s in t:
    ## get a list of the timestamp and the data values from the list of dictionaries
    row = [s['time']] + list(s['data']['instant']['details'].values())
    ## append the row to the data list
    data.append(row)

## make a dataframe from the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)

## save dataframe to CSV
filepath = r'C:\Temp\myData.csv'  ## change to a relevant path
df.to_csv(filepath, index=False)  ## index=False omits the row number of the dataframe from the CSV

## add the CSV as table 'layer' in QGIS
csv_lyr = QgsVectorLayer(filepath, 'csv ' + name)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(csv_lyr)
```

Comment: # Python Console
# Use iface to access QGIS API interface or type help(iface) for more info
# Security warning: typing commands from an untrusted source can harm your computer
exec(open('C:/Users/.../test.py'.encode('utf-8')).read()) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3170, in to_csv

Comment: continuation - formatter.save()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 185, in save
    f, handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 493, in get_handle
    f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, errors=errors, newline="")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Temp\\myData.csv'

Comment: You need to change the filepath (and filename) in the line `filepath = r'C:\Temp\myData.csv'` to wherever you want to save the result

Answer (score 0):

If you are not well with programming, you can always choose an option for web-based converters like this below:

https://www.convertcsv.com/geojson-to-csv.htm

It will, unfortunately, require you to save your data as a separate file and upload it to the converter.

Comment: The problem is that this CSV has only 2 properties, both of which are nested dictionaries (3 or 4 tiers deep) that contain the data. I wrote the script to extract data from this specific GeoJSON.

Comment: I gave you just an example of one converter, but there are at least a few more. However, if you wrote the script, I am sure, that you will sort this out!

Comment: The converter works well to simply convert the GeoJSON to a CSV, but it puts all of the nested dictionaries as data in 1 cell, whereas my script unnests the values and splits them into rows.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried to split them i.e. in Excel? - Data - Text to columns?

Comment: That would work if the data were delimited strings on separate rows, but they are not. Due to the formatting of this particular GeoJSON, after the conversion it is one long delimited string with no way to determine linebreaks. Take a look at the output of https://www.convertcsv.com/geojson-to-csv.htm using the link in the question and you will see what I mean :) If you figure out a way using the converter then please add the information to your answer