# QGIS extract data from one column in data attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a problem similar to this question somewhat...

[GeoJSON format to CSV](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421023/geojson-format-to-csv/421039#421039)

where everything is bounded in just one column instead of a few as it should be.

I have both `<br>` and the `:` separators.
Is it possible to set up some formula extracting the data to each separate column?

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

After the search & replace function discussed in the comment below I got something like this:

[image]

and as you can see I need these titles in the column head instead of every 2nd column. Is it possible?

Comment: Did I correctly understand you : instead of having *'Institution and Organisation:Makerere University, UFRIC <br>...<br>'* in one column, you would like to have three columns with values: *'Institution and Organisation'* , *'Makerere University, UFRIC '*, and *'...'*?

Comment: Yes indeed! I want all these data in the separate columns, but I don't know how to cope with it.

Comment: Open and edit your CSV in a text editor. Replace `<br>` with `:`

Answer (score 1):

For problems like this, I usually extract the layer as csv and then import extracted data to LibreOffice Calc.

In LibreOffice Calc (or Excel) you can select the column and use "text to columns" tool in data tab and select "seprated by" and set the character you want to split data with that, in your case `<br>`. After that the column will be divided to two columns.

[image]

pay attention if you do not set geometry as xy When outputting to csv You may have trouble retrieving it to qgis again.[image]
Maybe it's not the best way but always worked for me.

Comment: Your solution could be fine for simple data. I have followed the hints provided in the comments and finally you can see my result in the next image uploaded.